# How to stop Android's CountDownTimer?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have set up an anonymous class that contains an implementation of Android's CountDownTimer. However, CountDownTimer does not seem to stop after the call to `onFinish()` has been made.

I've tried to use `cancel()` to stop CountDownTimer, but the result is the same: CountDownTimer does not stop after the call to `onFinish()`

Here is the code I am running:

```
CountDownTimer cTimer = null;
cTimer = new CountDownTimer(array[onValue] * 1000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        important.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
    public void onFinish() { }
};
cTimer.start();
important.setText("Test"); //does not run
```

Comment: how do you ascertain that it is not finished?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it does eventually finish, but the time it takes to get to ```important.setText("Test");``` is impractical. Is there a way I can move on to ```important.setText("Test");``` right after the call to onFinish() has been made?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The timer is not in a seperate thread, and anything beyond the anon class has to wait for the CountDownTimer to complete